The new AI search feature's "Save as Q&A" button is in blatant violation of the community's ban on generative AI
On 2024-10-01, the company rolled out a new AI search feature that includes a button to post the genAI answer (along with a new question that has to be written from scratch) straight to main:



This button should not exist, as it is a blatant violation of the community's ban on generative AI. AI-generated content is not allowed on main - period. Remove the button.

As a side-note, though the button is currently broken, the source code indicates that it at least posts a genAI answer to main:



This form includes an answer key, that explicitly includes the text "This answer was generated by OverflowAI", and contains the AI-generated answer verbatim. If the feature worked as intended, it would be posting generated answers to main, as admitted by the answer body. Testing indicates that it requires manually writing a question, so it looks like at least the answer would be AI-generated, in blatant violation of the genAI ban.

FWIW, clicking the button gives you an error. Most likely because this was rolled out by mistake - I think it is a Teams-only feature.

Seeing how it works, I'd be worried about the reputational damage this would do as a teams feature

@VLAZ I don't get an error on SO: https://i.sstatic.net/TVLW8iJj.png - doesn't seem to populate anything in the question though

@Zoe-Savethedatadump maybe a mod privilege? I get this generic error

@VLAZ More like mod curse in this case :p Checked devtools too, and the request is indeed a 200. Rollout bug maybe?

I don't think we can really say that it's in violation of anything unless it...well, does something.  (also, I strongly suspect that this feature wasn't intended to appear on the public network at all)

Yep, the error makes me think rollout bug. If I click the button, the browser goes to /ai-enhanced-search/save-question and I get a 302 redirection to /error https://i.sstatic.net/rE5el6Kk.png

I checked under a sock account as well (28 rep), where it also works and redirects to the wizard

@RyanM I'd assume the teams codebase and SE ones are not 'the same' and even if they were, well, this seems like a pretty big deployment mistake

@JourneymanGeek Pretty sure it would also be a first. I don't think there's ever been an accident where something was pushed to main that was meant to be teams-only

@RyanM The POST request, though currently broken, includes the genAI answer verbatim under a hidden answer field: https://i.sstatic.net/rUiyWYbk.png, including a nice "This answer was generated by OverflowAI". If it worked, it would be publishing genAI answers to main, in violation of the genAI ban

@Zoe-Savethedatadump not the first actually, here's an example from a few months ago where somehow the search help linked to Teams articles.

"Love" that's closed as [[meta-tag:status-norepro]], @AbdulAzizBarkat ; presumbly because the bad deployment was rolled back before a member of staff looked at the question.

@Zoe I mean...sure, if you assume that this was intentional.  I am not currently assuming that, because all available evidence suggests that it was an error...in which case, if it worked, it wouldn't be showing up at all on the public network.  Let's wait and find out which one it is before we declare whether it's a violation.

@VLAZ Some further testing seems to indicate that the button doesn't error if you have the wizard enabled. I get the same error when the wizard is disabled, so it's only half broken. Posted a test question a while ago, and the genAI answer was not posted immediately, and hasn't magically appeared since (admittedly, I instantly deleted, so there's a chance that stopped the answer from being posted if it's posted separately by a bot account or something)

And now it's gone.

If the answer admits to being completely generated by AI then you can still flag it asking mods to delete it.

The old "do not attribute to malice what can be explained by a failed deployment" adage strikes again.

@yivi SE has already threatened to roll out some form of genAI feature later this week. Failed deployment in this case doesn't necessarily mean "this is a teams feature", it could be "it was supposed to be deployed later this week"

Not only is it against AI policy, but offering to turn a search result into a new Q&A sounds a lot like offering to create useless duplicates on purpose.

@KarlKnechtel it would make sense as a teams feature, though, to.... "duplicate" SO content on a teams instance

Thank you for flagging this to us!
This was not supposed to have been released publicly — it was an accidental turning on of the feature that had been previously tested, but there is no new test.
To be clear, there are no current plans to release this on the public platform, even in the future. We've turned it back off.
Apologies for the hiccup!

"To be clear, there are no current plans to release this on the public platform, even in the future" Given this claim, and the fact it is a feature that completely violates a site-wide rule banning AI content, maybe the code should be entirely removed from the codebase, then? There is no scenario where such a feature can co-exist while said site-wide rule is in place.

Is there any risk of a more enthusiastic user preparing an HTTP request that triggers the feature?

@Augusto I'm certainly not staff, but that's generally not how turning deployed platform features on or off works. Their system will look to their own configuration setup to determine whether a feature is enabled or not– I can't think of anything an end-user could do to disrupt that if it's set up correctly.

@zcoop98, I didn't suggest turning the feature on or off by user. I was thinking about the feature end point being available even if not documented.

I don't recall any such test, The OverflowAI search feature was quite a bit different from this.

@TylerH presumably they figure the ban doesn't apply to SOfT.

@KarlKnechtel Which is correct. What companies do with the private information on their own teams is not our problem, and doesn't affect the Q&A that actually matters for knowledge sharing

Except this isn't SOfT. It's SO. While some codebase may be shared, code for this should not be. Anything AI-related should be in a separate module loaded specially for SOfT since we don't want AI content on our site.

This still begs the question of why SE was putting so much effort into developing a GPT-like search, when the platform's "unique selling point" is the collection of  trustworthy expertise (admittedly, far too often of poor quality - that's where an AI could help, as well as the terrible auto-detection of related posts). Probably not a violation, but at least it's highly contradictory and not comprehensible to users. Also, how could this feature possibly attract new members to SO, as it completely undermines the concept of participation - no new questions, no new answers.

@herrstrietzel - Money. SE can be paid money for data to train AI, why not utilize that trained AI, I get it. But it doesn’t mean that any contribution generated by AI will be helpful, and until I see a single helpful contribution by AI I will continue to downvote, vote to delete, and flag AI generated content.
